# Do C99 signed integer types defined in stdint.h exhibit well-defined behaviour in case of an overflow?

Tags: c, standards, c99, integer-overflow

All operations on "standard" signed integer types in C (short, int, long, etc) exhibit undefined behaviour if they yield a result outside of the [TYPE_MIN, TYPE_MAX] interval (where TYPE_MIN, TYPE_MAX are the minimum and the maximum integer value respectively. that can be stored by the specific integer type.

According to the C99 standard, however, all `intN_t` types are required to have a two's complement representation:

> **7.8.11.1 Exact-width integer types**
>   1. The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width N , no padding
>   bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus, int8_t denotes a signed integer
>   type with a width of exactly 8 bits.

Does this mean that `intN_t` types in C99 exhibit well-defined behaviour in case of an integer overflow? For example, is this code well-defined?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Minimum 32-bit representable number: %" PRId32 "\n", INT32_MAX + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

The requirement for a 2's-complement representation for values within the range of the type does not imply anything about the behavior on overflow.

The types in `<stdint.h>` are simply typedefs (aliases) for existing types.  Adding a typedef doesn't change a type's behavior.

Section 6.5 paragraph 5 of the C standard (both C99 and C11) still applies:

> If an *exceptional condition* occurs during the evaluation of an
>   expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or
>   not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior
>   is undefined.

This doesn't affect unsigned types because unsigned operations do not overflow; they're defined to yield the wrapped result, reduced modulo *TYPE*_MAX + 1. Except that unsigned types narrower than `int` are promoted to (signed) `int`, and can therefore run into the same problems. For example, this:

```
unsigned short x = USHRT_MAX;
unsigned short y = USHRT_MAX;
unsigned short z = x * y;
```

causes undefined behavior if `short` is narrower than `int`. (If `short` and `int` are 16 and 32 bits, respectively, then `65535 * 65535` yields `4294836225`, which exceeds `INT_MAX`.)

Comment: Is this mentioned implicitly or explicitly somewhere in the standard?

Comment: 6.5p5, which I quoted, mentions it explicitly.  Nothing else in the standard says implies that 6.5p5 doesn't apply to the `intN_t` types.  And nothing in the standard defines the common wraparound behavior for 2's-complement types; for the behavior to be defined, the standard would have to define it somewhere.

Comment: "This doesn't affect unsigned types because ..."  Should not this be qualified as unsigned types narrower that `int` are promoted to `int` (and not `unsigned`) first and then they suffer the same behavior limitations?

Answer (score 4):

Although storing an out-of-range value to a signed type *stored in memory* will generally store the bottom bits of the value, and reloading the value from memory will sign-extend it, many compilers' optimizations may assume that signed arithmetic won't overflow, and the effects of overflow may be unpredictable in many real scenarios.  As a simple example, on a 16-bit DSP which uses its one 32-bit accumulator for return values (e.g. TMS3205X), `int16_t foo(int16_t bar) { return bar+1;}` a compiler would be free to load `bar`, sign-extended, into the accumulator, add one to it, and return.  If the calling code were e.g. `long z = foo(32767)`, the code might very well set `z` to 32768 rather than -32768.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Could the example have been corrected as `long foo(int bar) {return bar+1;}`? I've used a compiler for a DSP where `int` was 16 bits, but the processor's only 32-bit accumulator was used to return function results. If such a function were called by `long z = foo(32767)+1`; the compiler would likely assign `z` a value of +32769 rather than -32767 [the calling code would add one to the accumulator, and then store both halves]. I don't remember the exact cases that yielded 'interesting' behaviors, but there were some.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Also, I find the language you cite curious. Would every possible "value" of an `int16` expression (including implementation-defined ones) be required to be one that could be stored without modification in an `int16` variable? I find it interesting that out-of-range arithmetic is totally "undefined behavior", but out-of-range conversions allow "implementation-defined signals".

Comment: Yes, that example seems like a reasonable case where the undefined behavior could do something entirely unexpected in light of the type system.  For the first example, yes I believe that if there is no signal, the result must be a valid `int16_t` value.  The most reasonable actual behaviors are bitmasking (modulo arithmetic just like unsigned) and saturation (which some hardware does implement).

Comment: @BenVoigt: Incidentally, for reasons somewhat alluded to by my example, I'm somewhat dubious of efforts to replace all occurrences of types like `unsigned int` with types like `uint32_t`, given that `int` and `unsigned int` have a semantic meaning as the minimum sizes to which signed or unsigned integral expressions will be promoted. If code compares an `int` and an `unsigned int`, the comparison is specified to be unsigned; by comparison, a comparison between `int16_t` and `uint16_t`, or between `int32_t` and `uint32_t`, could be signed or unsigned depending upon size of int.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Another question alluded to an even nastier example, btw: Given `uint32_t x=0xFFFFFFFF`, would `x=(x*x);` set `x` to 1 or would it cause Undefined Behavior?  Would `x*=x;` be any different?

Comment: What are the options?  1. it got promoted to its own type.  Then the result is `((2**32-1) * (2**32-1)) % (2**32)` which is `-1`.  2. It got promoted to a larger signed type.  Then the result is `((2**32-1) * (2**32-1))` iff that result is representable, and otherwise UB.  No, `x*=x` isn't different, except that if `int` can represent `((2**32-1) * (2**32-1))`, it will get stored in `x` as `1` (because coercion to `unsigned` types is performed using modulo arithmetic)

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's why I offered it up as a nasty example. One wouldn't expect code which works on machines with a 32-bit `int` type to cause overflow on machines with 64-bit `int`, but in the above example it can.