# What are the possible values after int32 overflow?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I have a function that takes a string as input, and then assigns a product of weighted values to a variable, in the following manner: every letter of the alphabet corresponds to a prime number between 2 and 101, and the value for every character in the input string is multiplied and stored in an int variable, like so:

```
int result=1;
/* some other code */
result*=letterweight[index];
```

There are sufficiently long strings that cause an overflow. My question, then, is the following:

How can I determine the *possible correct* values, given a result?

For instance: if `result == 1066849907`, what other value could result have had, neglecting the values range of `int` in C?

I do not have control of the original code and cannot determine *if* an overflow occurred. I am only interested in finding out the series of possible results, however big the numbers might be.

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior, you can't rely on anything.

Answer (score 5):

Signed integer overflow (in C as well as C++) results in undefined behavior, so you cannot reason about your code in this way. You can only test your specific compiler/version and see what it produces.

However, this is a horrible way to write code and will bite you in the future.  Your proposal is not a solution.  How about pre-processing the data and removing values which would cause overflow?

Answer (score 1):

Signed integer overflow - unlike unsigned integer overflow - is *undefined behaviour* in C and C++ ([see this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c)).

If you make the arithmetic `unsigned int` however, the standard guarantees modulo 2 arithmetic, in other words, the range of possible, *real* values is `result + 2^(sizeof(unsigned int) * 8) * a` for any `a`.

Comment: The set described in this answer is not the set of possible values; it includes some that are not possible. As Dukeling noted, any number with a prime factor greater than 101 is not possible. (Additionally, the multiplier should be `CHAR_BIT` rather than 8.)

Comment: The range of possible values you quoted is incorrect: There is no guarantee that `char` uses 8 bit. The correct upper bound is `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` which will be some power of 2.