# Type casting differnce

Tags: c++, algorithm, syntax

In the following code :

```
#include<cstdio>
#define max(a,b) (a>b?a:b)
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int f=10000000;

    long long i=(long long)max(1000000,f*f);
    printf("%lld",i);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the output of

> 276447232

But if I write

```
long long i=max((long long)1000000,(long long)f*f);
```

I get the output of

> 100000000000000

What is the difference between the two lines? Why doesn't the type conversion occur in the first case?

Comment: What would you expect `float f = (float)(3/4);` to assign to `f`?

Comment: BTW. `(long long)100000000` is equivalent to `100000000LL`

Comment: @MatthewMoss: That is an _answer_; please post it as such, not in the comments.

Answer (score 6):

This line says: "take the max of these two `int` values, the latter of which will overflow. Then take the result and cast it to `long long`". By the time the `long long` cast is called in the first case, it is too late. [Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c).

```
long long i=(long long)max(1000000,f*f)
```

This line says: "take the max of these two `long long` values and return it". The reason `(long long)f*f` works is because it is casting the first `f` to `long long` before the multiplication, due to precedence. The second `f` is then promoted to `long long` for the multiplication to occur.

```
long long i=max((long long)1000000,(long long)f*f);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you expand the macro in this line:

```
long long i=(long long)max(1000000,f*f);
```

You get:

```
long long i=(long long)(1000000>f*f?1000000:f*f)
```

The term in the parenthesis is data type int, so f*f is computed as an integer and overflows wrapping around to a value < 1000000.

Comment: Doesn't really matter whether `max` is implemented as a macro or an actual function.

Answer (score 0):

Due to [C++ operator precedence rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence),

```
(long long)f*f
```

typecasts before multiplication. That is, that expression is the same as:

```
((long long) f) * f
```

Because one of the arguments to the multiplication is a `long long`, the other argument (i.e. the bare `f`) is implicitly promoted to `long long` as well, and `long long` multiplication is performed with a `long long` result, avoiding overflow.

Had, instead, the multiplication operator preceded typecasting, then the expression would be interpreted as:

```
(long long) (f * f)
```

The multiplication, having two `int` arguments, would perform `int` multiplication, which given the value of `f`, overflows first and *then* is typecast to `long long`.

To be clear about your question,

> Why doesn't the type conversion occur in the first case?

It does; but it occurs too late.