# Why can I convert 65535+1 to a valid int in C++?

Tags: c++, integer, overflow

I have a really simple program:

```
int main()
{
  char* num = new char[5];
  sprintf(num, "65536");
  std::cout << "atoi(num): " << atoi(num) << "\n";
}
```

The max size of an unsigned INT is 65535. Why doesn't this program overflow when I run `atoi(65536)`?

Comment: Did you run your program through a memory debugger like Valgrind or ASAN?

Comment: note that "65536" won't fit into a char[5].  you need to allocate space for the null character

Comment: Maybe your assumption of the maximum size if an unsigned int is wrong? Check `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`. Also note you have undefined behaviour because `num` is not null-terminated.

Comment: @juanchopanza, so it looks like the reference I was using was wrong. The max unsigned int would be `2147483647`. However, `atoi()` still doesn't break under these conditions. What concept am I missing?

Comment: @n0pe It isn't wrong or right. `unsigned int` has to be at least 16 bits. That's all. You have to check what it is on your platform. But it is *extremely* likely to be 32 bits.

Comment: Why are you guys keep talking about `unsigned int` when `atoi` is used?

Comment: Is this what you want to see? http://rextester.com/ERIGHP50494

Comment: @Rostislav is the size of int and of unsigned int different on the same system? Also, the question was about unsigned int, not about atoi ;)

Comment: @Rostislav: That is undfined behaviour on most systems (including the smaller ones). So it proves just nothing.

Comment: @Olaf Yep, I know, just wanted to understand what the OP actually expected :)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Many platforms I use have 16 bit `int`. IIRC, one even had non-standard 8 bit `int`.

Comment: @Serge While the size is the same, the range of values is different, which is kinda important in this case, but given that the question is kind of underspecified, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Rostislav: I'm actually not sure OP knows himself. I'm still waiting for clarification about `MAX_INT` (or whatever C++ provides).

Comment: @Olaf Yeah. Well, if I'd write an answer it would certainly include a note about UB (IN HUGE LETTERS :)), but these are comments so I felt it was somewhat out of place.

Comment: @n0pe: `UINT_MAX == 2147483647` is very unlikely, as that is 31 1-bits. It might be `INT_MAX`, though.

Comment: @Rostislav, yes, I agree, of course. Anyway, the statement that `int` type in C and C++ is `at least 16 bits wide` is true, and all questions you and @Olaf put  are legit

Comment: `atoi` is dumb as a post. It returns 0 on utterly failed conversions (converting "the" for example), halts with and doesn't tell you where ("10the" returns 10) gleefully reads past the max value of `int` without warning ("5000000000" may return  705032704). Don't use it unless you've already strenuously tested the input. Use the likes of [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) (and test for proper size and proper end pointer location) or [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (and handle the thrown exceptions for bad input).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On current PC systems, an `int` is usually 32 bits or even 64 bits (except one some smaller platforms such as Arduino).

So, probably on your system an `int` (or `unsigned int`) is larger than 16 bits and 65536 should not overflow. You could easily check this with:

```
std::cout << sizeof(int) << "\n";
```

Also, there is no space in `num` for the null-terminator:

```
char* num = new char[5];
sprintf(num, "65536");
```

So `sprintf()` will write a terminating `\0` one past your buffer, causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

> There is no way to limit the number of characters written, which means
>   that code using `sprintf` is susceptible to buffer overruns.

This should be changed to:

```
char* num = new char[6];
```

Comment: An `int` is usually 16 bits, not 32. If you count CPu cores which use it, the number with smaller `int` outnumbers the ones with 32 bit `int` by decades. And there are also `int` with 64 bits or - more exotic nowadays - 24 or 18 bits. The standard does not define a specific bit-size for int or the other integer types, but only a minimum range.

Comment: not sure what it is in c++ but in java an int is 32 -bit

Comment: And there is no need to terminate `num` before calling `sprintf`. The problem is not missing trermination, but not enough entries being allocated (as you apparently noticed). `sprintf` will very well write a terminator - just out of bounds.

Comment: @Ibukun: Maybe there is a reason they are supposed to be different languages. Same syntax/grammar does not imply same semantics.

Comment: Btw, integer overflow is undefined behaviour. So it may very well show strange results. But - acknowledged - this is not likely.

Comment: @Olaf - _" sprintf will very well write a terminator - just out of bounds."_ - Yes, I've seen that in the debugger, I meant no \0 in the array, I'll rephrase it.

Comment: Actually, for 16 bit `int`, `32768` already will overflow, thus invoke UB.

Comment: Happily removed the DV. Maybe you can still clarify that writing beyound array boundaries is UB. One can never emphasise that enough :-(

Comment: @NathanOliver Is it not UB? [standardese quote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16188846/3589890)

Comment: UV for adding the notes about UB and `sprintf`. I don't work much with these functions. On embedded they are useless and on PC I use Python.

Comment: @olaf my mistake.  I had it confused with bit shifting

Comment: @NathanOliver: Not sure about C++, but in C, left-shift also has potential for UB. Only certain right-shifts are IB (strange enough. I tend to treat both as UB, thus my common advise is just not to shift signed integers).

Comment: @Olaf - Thanks - actually I also don't use sprintf much. (Oh, and I love those 16 bit systems, just don't have enough time to _work_ with them).

Comment: @Danny_ds: While I like some of the the smaller 8 or 16 bitters, I'm quite happy with the Cortex-M 32 bitters right now. Not much use in the smaller ones unless you need very low power. OTOH, once hobby becomes job, there are always ups and downs.