# USING A LOOP, multiply all of the numbers between 3 and 8

Tags: c++, loops

I'm not totally sure where to start with this program.  I was just introduced to loops and have done a couple simple loops.  This question doesn't make sense to me.  Basically it is supposed to read

```
answer is 3
answer is 12
answer is 60
answer is 360
answer is 2520
answer is 20160
```

I can make it read this but only by hard coding... Do I use while statements? if statements? else statements?  I am so lost and have been trying for about an hour already.

Comment: Show what you've tried, and tell us what problem you encountered.

Comment: How would 3 be a product of numbers between 3 and 8?

Comment: @Codor `3` and no other operands

Comment: it's pretty hard to say anything about this without just giving the answer ...

Comment: how do I show what I have

Answer (score 4):

The problem could be solved with one `for` loop as follows.

```
int Product = 1;

for (int i = 3; i <= 8; i++)
{
    Product = Product * i;
    // if desired, do something useful with Product
}
```

Comment: This doesn't match the required output. It's actually much easier to do with a single loop multiplying onto some variable

Comment: Yes, I somewhat misunderstood question. The desired outcome in total would be 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8, not some pairwise products.

Comment: @Codor Me too..I didn't read the question well. I thought it was to print the pattern infinitely.. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

This follows a pattern

```
3*4 = 12
(3*4)*5 = 12 * 5 = 60
(3*4*5)*6 = 60 * 6 = 360
(3*4*5*6)*7 = 360 * 7 = 2520
(3*4*5*6*7)*8 = 2520 * 8 = 20160
```

code in C++

```
     int result = 1;
     for(int i =3; i<=8;i++)
     {
         result = result * i;
         cout<<"answer is"<<result;
     }
```

Comment: `for(counter = 4 ; counter>0; counter++)` certainly doesn't look right.

Comment: @dasdingonesin It works. I tried it in JS. Please remove the down vote if you did it.

Comment: 1. The question is about C++, not JavaScript. 2. The question asks how to multiply the numbers from 3 to 8, not from 3 to signed integer overflow, i.e. undefined behaviour.

Comment: @dasdingonesin Its for infinite loop

Comment: [No, it isn't.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c) Also, why would you want an infinite loop?

Comment: @dasdingonesin I didn't notice upto 8 condition.

Comment: Eh, `for (var counter = 4; counter > 200000; counter++)`? The body of that loop will not be executed a single time.

Comment: @dasdingonesin Now its working...Please verify it and remove the downvote

Comment: @phresnel I corrected the code. I was only constructing it. sory or the stupid mistake please verify it now

Comment: @rozina Please see the 2nd  edits of my answer....run this code     int accumulator = 3;
    for(counter = 4 ; counter>0; counter++)
    {
       printf("Answer is %d \n", counter);
       accumulator = accumulator * counter;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
int out = 1;
for (int i = 3; i < 9; ++i)
{
    out *= i;
    cout << out << endl;
}
```