# C++ - Assigning int to char then assigning char to another int

Tags: casting, char, int

I have this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(int n, char** args)
{
    int i = 140;
    char c = i;
    int j = c;
    printf("%d", j);
    system("pause");
}
```

Output:

> -116

As I understand, `char c = i` would assign the character which has ASCII code 140 to `c`, but I wonder what happened when assigning `int j = c;` after that and where does `-116` value come from?

if I change `char c = i;` to `unsigned char c = i;` then the output is `140`.
Is there anyway to get the value of `j` equal to `140` if I don't use `unsigned` here? (assumed that i >= 0 and i <= 255)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [range of values for an unsigned char](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Range_of_values) are `[0,255]` inclusive - but the range of values for a signed char are `[-128,127]` inclusive.

Your value of `140` is outside the range of the signed char, so it overflows and wraps round to `-116`. At least that's what seems to be happening - overflow of a signed integer is [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c).

There's not really any way to avoid this without using `unsigned char` or a larger alternative to `char` - you're simply trying to represent a value that can't be represented by that type.