# Pretty confused about C++ Exception Handling

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception, integer-overflow

Trying to add exception handling to my C++ program, but I find it pretty confusing. The program sets the values i and j to their highest possible values and increments them. I think I want the exception handling to detect the integer overflow / wraparound when it happens(?)

So far this is what I've got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i;
    unsigned int j;

    try{
            i = INT_MAX;
            i++;
            cout<<i;
    }
    catch( const std::exception& e){
    cout<<"Exception Error!";
    }   


    try{
            j = UINT_MAX;
            j++;
            cout<<j;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e){
    cout<<"Exception Error!";
    }
}
```

The program runs, but the exception handling part doesn't work.

What could be the issue?

Comment: The issue is that overflow isn't specified to throw exceptions. So if you are expecting it to, you have a misconception about C++.

Comment: Unsigned integer overflow wraps around in a well-defined way. Signed integer overflow leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), which may or may not result in wrap around, getting a large negative number, resulting in a crash, an exception or maybe even nothing happening at all.

Answer (score 6):

Well the behaviour of incrementing `i` beyond `INT_MAX` is *undefined*. That's because it's a signed integral type. I've never come across an implementation that throws an exception in this case. (Typical behaviour is *wrap-around* to `INT_MIN` but **don't** rely on that.)

Incrementing `j` beyond `UINT_MAX` *must* wrap-around to 0. That's because it's an `unsigned` type. That is, an exception must *never* be thrown.

Comment: I can think of three possible implementation of signed overflow, all of which are more likely than an exception being thrown: 1. Wrap around, 2. Saturation at `INT_MAX`, 3. Process being killed with a signal.

Comment: How can I find that situation is _undefined_ ? Can you share a reliable source ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c

Answer (score 3):

C++ does not define any exceptions to be thrown in case of integer overflow. If you want to achive such behavior you will need some wrapper for integer class with corresponding functionality, such as [Safe Int library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd570023.aspx). Example:

```
#include <safeint.h>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        ::msl::utilities::SafeInt<int> j;
        for(;;)
        {
            ++j;
        }
    }
    catch(::msl::utilities::SafeIntException const & exception)
    {
        switch(exception.m_code)
        {
            case ::msl::utilities::SafeIntArithmeticOverflow:
            {
                ::std::cout << "overflow detected" << ::std::endl;
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: "C++ does throw any exceptions ....".    I suspect you need the word "not" in there.

Comment: @Peter: Neither case is strictly true. The signed case is UB, which could, of course, manifest itself in throwing an exception. But despite that, I think the author's intention is how you describe it. So I've made an edit.

Comment: @Bathesda - The C++ standard does not require an exception to be thrown, either way.

Comment: @Peter: Absolutely. Isn't that what I said?

Answer (score 0):

In C++, exceptions don’t just happen. Exceptions are thrown by the `throw` keyword; if your code (or code you’ve linked to) doesn’t have `throw something()` it doesn’t throw exceptions.

That’s not quite true, however: there are funky situations where the code does something inappropriate (formally, the code has undefined behavior), which **might** result in an exception being thrown. That’s outside the rules of the language definition, so not portable and not reliable (yes, I’m looking at you, Windows SEH).