# C# date types convertion same as c++

Tags: c#, c++, native, long-integer, ulong

How do I convert ulong to long with same result as I get in c++.

**C++**

```
unsigned long ul = 3633091313;
long l = (long)ul;
l is -661875983
```

**C#**

```
ulong ul = 3633091313;
long l = (long)ul;
l is 3633091313
```

Comment: You **want** an overflow error? Because that is what the C++ example is, a error. The .NEt Long is a 64 bit signed integer. So the maximum is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/long) As opposed to native C++ Long is only 32 bit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++'s `long` is often a 32-bit data type. It looks like in your system it does not have enough bits to represent `3633091313`, so the result is negative. This behavior is undefined in C++ ([relevant Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16188846/335858)).

In C# that corresponds to converting to `int`:

```
UInt64 ul = 3633091313UL;
Int32 l = (int)ul;
Console.WriteLine(l); // prints -661875983
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/kdjiBO)

Comment: Maybe we should be using the int[binarity] here, rather then the type alias "int" and "ulong"? The width of the type in memory seems to be a important feature. For whatever wierd reason.

Comment: @Christopher You are right, showing the proper size is more descriptive. Thank you!