# int16 overflow leading to infinite loop

Tags: c++, int, integer-overflow

As we know, int16_t has a max value 32767, so the following code will just loop:

```
for (int16_t i = 0; i < 65535; i++) {
  // infinite loop
}
```

When I change the code, it loops as well:

```
const int32_t t = 65535;
for (int16_t i = 0; i < t; i++) {
  // infinite loop
}
```

But when I make it uint32_t instead of int32_t, it actually exits:

```
const uint32_t t = 65535;
for (int16_t i = 0; i < t; i++) {
  // actually exits
}
```

Is this due to some compiler trick it does for me? I assume when I do the comparison:

```
i < t
```

For the last version it does auto convert for me? But I don't understand why it exits in the last version still...

Comment: ++ is an assembly like instruction, so just after 32767 you will see -1, -2, ..- as you may expect < is cmp instruction (in fact - ) and  loop never ends

Comment: @VictorGubin His question is about the last version, which *does* end.

Comment: Your title is misleading. Your question is about the loop that isn't infinite.

Comment: BTW, you should increase your warnings level https://wandbox.org/permlink/Igrl9FdrbP1TxyJB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you compare a signed type and unsigned type, the signed type is promoted to an an unsigned type before the comparison is performed. Hence, the last block of code works.

---

Take a look at the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
   const uint32_t t = 65535;
   int16_t i = 32765;
   for (; i < t; i++)
   {
      std::cout << i << ", " << static_cast<uint32_t>(i) << std::endl;
   }
   std::cout << i << ", " << static_cast<uint32_t>(i) << std::endl;
}
```

and its output with g++  6.4.0

```
32765, 32765
32766, 32766
32767, 32767
-32768, 4294934528
```

At the point of integer overflow, the value of `i` flips from the maximum value to the minimum value. More importantly, when that number is promoted to `uint32_t`, it appears to be a large value.

The binary representation of `4294934528` in `uint32_t` is:

```
11111111 11111111 10000000 00000000
```

The binary representation of `-32768` in `int16_t` is:

```
                  10000000 00000000
```

There seems to be a correlation there although I don't fully understand what the rules of promoting an signed type to an unsigned type are to explain the correlation.

Comment: There's no undefined behaviour here, if `int` is 32-bit. The `int16_t` will be promoted to `int` before `++` happens

Comment: @M.M, You are probably right but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c.

Comment: @RSahu what part of that question do you refer to? After the promotion, incrementing the int `32767` yields the int `32768` , there is no overflow

Comment: @M.M, doesn't that count as overflow for a variable of type `int16_t`?

Comment: @RSahu the *integer promotions* promote the value to `int` before the increment is applied

Comment: @M.M, and the resulting `int` is simply truncated to 16 bits before it is assigned to the variable?

Comment: @M.M and then the `int` value is assigned to `i` which is `int16_t`. If the value is too large to be represented it will give implementation-defined behaviour.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion