# is there any problem to use abs instead of labs or fabs?

Tags: c++

I would like to know the difference of abs,labs and fabs. This is under the cstdlib header file. So, I got confused to use these words in cpp programming.

Comment: they are different functions for different datatypes. What confuses you?

Comment: I dont understand the usage of these words.

Comment: What would you like to know that's not on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs? As-is, this question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: what specifically you dont understand? We cannot know what is your current level, for example it could be that you dont know how to call a function. Do you know how to call a function?

Comment: Example of on-topic question: "_In the following [mcve] `#include <cst...`, which function should I use to compute the absolute value: `abs`, `labs` or `fabs`?_"

Answer (score 1):

```
int abs(int n)
```

This function returns the absolute value of `n` being `n` an `int` variable.

```
long int labs(long int n)
```

This function returns the absolute value of parameter `n` as `long int` type instead of `int`.

```
float fabs(float n)
```

This function returns the absolute value of parameter `n` as `float` type variable.

There are still these overloads for `double` and `long double` types:

```
double fabs (double x); //for double variables
long double fabs (long double x); //for long double variables
```

For these overloads the compiler will choose the correct version deppending on the parameter type.

The difference is clear, you should use the correct version of `abs()` deppending on the parameter variable type you are using, the wrong usage may result in [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) namely due to [signed integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c).

Comment: your last sentence can be misread. There are implicit conversions, so the type of the parameter must not necessarily be the same as the type of the argument.

Comment: @idclev463035818, yes, I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

the only difference is the return type and the parameter type.
`abs()` takes an integer as a parameter and also return an integer, 
`fabs()` takes and returns a floating point type like a float or double
`labs()` takes and returns a long int.
So simply use the appropriate one for the data you're dealing with.
check this link https://learntechway.com/abs-fabs-labs-in-c/