# Prime Printer won't print primes. Prints everything instead

Tags: c++, vector, primes

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

//vector<int> primes;

bool isPrime(int c, vector<int> p){
    for(int i = 0; i<p.size(); i++){
        int prime = p[i];
        if(prime*prime > c) return true;
        if(c%prime == 0) return false;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<int> primes;
    primes.push_back(2);
    for(int n = 3; n>1; n++){
        if(isPrime(n, primes)){
            primes.push_back(n);
            cout << n << endl;
         }//else cout << "no" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anything specific causing the problem? Because it shouldn't be printing every number.

Comment: `for(int n = 3; n>1; n++)`? That looks odd. What do you mean to do here?

Comment: Step through a non-prime in your debugger.

Comment: How your `isPrime` is supposed to work? Can you describe the algorithm?

Comment: The for loop didn't need a conditional, but if there was an integer overflow or something that would hopefully make it stop, it starts at 3 because I added 2 already.

Comment: You should not rely on the program crashing as a method to stop a loop.

Comment: If your `int` overflows, then you have undefined behaviour, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c.

Comment: As for how isPrime works: basically it runs through each prime, if a prime's square is greater than the number, then you should have already found another prime that the number is divisible by but if you haven't then the number must be prime, otherwise check if the number is divisible by the prime and if it is then it can't be a prime.

Comment: I just ran your program here. It prints all the primes and nothing else -> voting to close.

Comment: Your code is fine, just fix the test condition of for loop and prevent it from being infinite. code gave correct results when I fixed it.

Comment: One improvement is to not pass the primes by value. [https://ideone.com/BaqS8R](https://ideone.com/BaqS8R)

Answer (score 2):

It probably must be going into infinite loop. `for(int n = 3; n>1; n++)` must be - `for(int n = 3; n<upper_limit; n++)`, where *upper_limit* is the max number upto which you want to print primes. The below code works -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

//vector<int> primes;

bool isPrime(int c, vector<int> p){
    for(int i = 0; i<p.size(); i++){
        int prime = p[i];
        if(prime*prime > c) return true;
        if(c%prime == 0) return false;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<int> primes;
    primes.push_back(2);
    for(int n = 3; n<10; n++){
        if(isPrime(n, primes)){
            primes.push_back(n);
            cout << n << endl;
         }//else cout << "no" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You program works as well...just that it prints primes forever until the memory runs out and it crashes (probably not what you want :) ). So, add a stop condition and it would run fine.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that it would crash before displaying an output, at least on my device.

Comment: Side note: Can save a bunch of copying by passing `p` by `const` reference.

Comment: `prime*prime > c` is prone to overflow when `c` is a prime near `INT_MAX`.  `if(prime > c/prime) return true;` fixes that at little cost as `c/prime` and `c%prime` often use shared code.