# Comparison of INT_MAX

Tags: c++

I tried comparing two INT_MAX and then comparing result of this with a integer and I'm getting this weird result.Could u please explain why this is happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
  int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int a = 2;
    int option1 = min(INT_MAX, 1+INT_MAX);
    cout << "Result 1 " << option1 << endl;
    cout << "Result 2" << min(option1, 1+a);
    return 0;
}
```

It's giving this output:

```
Output:
    Result 1 -2147483648
    Result 2-2147483648
```

According to me result 2 should be 3 but it's giving something else.I'm not getting the reason behind this different output.

Comment: what do you expect to get when you add 1 to the largest possible value?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Username checks out :)

Comment: Why do you expect `min(-2147483648, 3)` to be 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INT_MAX is the largest positive value you can store in a (signed) int, when you add 1 to that you get [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c).  It's not that surprising, though, as (unsigned int) 0x7FFFFFFF + 1 == 0x80000000 which is the value -2147483648 in two's complement.  Now you compare a large negative number with 3 and get the large negative value which would be as expected.

Answer (score 3):

This overflows

```
int option1 = min(INT_MAX, 1+INT_MAX);
```

The purpose of `INT_MAX` (or better: `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`) is, well, to be a constant for the maximal `int` value that can be represented with the number of bytes that an `int` is on your system. If you add `1` to it, this is a signed integer overflow.

Signed integer overflows result in undefined behaviour. You can't really reason about the output of your program, as anything might happen. Note that as @Thomas and @largest_prime_is_463035818 pointed out in the comments, unsigned integer overflow isn't UB, it wraps around.

Comment: i heard some rumors that it wont be UB in a soon to come version of C++. Anyhow, it should be "signed integer overfow is UB", because unsigend is fine

Comment: Pedantry: only _signed_ integer overflows (like here) result in UB. Unsigned integer overflows are well-defined.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, that should probably be mentioned. Thanks.