# can someone tell why am i getting this error?

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve this problem : [Third Maximum Number](https://leetcode.com/problems/third-maximum-number/)

but I was getting this error

> Line 4: Char 37: runtime error: signed integer overflow: -9223372036854775808 - 10 cannot be represented in type 'long long' (solution.cpp)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:13:37

this my code

```
class Solution {
public:
    int thirdMax(vector<int>& nums) {
        long long int mx = LLONG_MIN-10;
        long long int second_mx = LLONG_MIN-10;
        long long int  third_mx = LLONG_MIN-10;
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++){
            if(nums[i] > mx){
                mx = nums[i];
            }
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++){
            if(nums[i] != mx){
                if(nums[i] > second_mx){
                    second_mx = nums[i];
                }
            }
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++){
            if(nums[i] != mx && nums[i] != second_mx){
                if(nums[i] > third_mx){
                    third_mx = nums[i];
                }
            }
        }
        if(third_mx == LLONG_MIN){
            return mx;
        }
        return third_mx;
    }
};
```

can someone please tell me what does this error really means?

Comment: What compiler flags are you using? You should be getting some dire compiler warnings about `return mx` as your method's return type is `int` but `mx` is `long long int` (`int` is typically `int32_t` while `long long int` is typically `int64_t`). And if you are getting those warnings, why didn't you fix them before continuing?

Comment: Just what it says.   The result of `LLONG_MIN-10` cannot be stored in a `long long` (aka `long long int`).   Think about it.   `LLONG_MIN` is the minimum value (negative value furthest from zero since `long long` is a `signed` type) that can be stored in a `long long`.   `LLONG_MIN-10` is less than that minimum value, so cannot be stored in a `long long`.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```cpp
long long int mx = LLONG_MIN-10;
```

takes `LLONG_MIN`, the minimal value a `long long int` could store, and subtracts 10. Obviously, this value can not be stored in `long long` anymore, so this causes an overflow, [which results in undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c).

You program was run with the [Undefined Behavior Sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html), which detected this and gave you the error.