# Code analysis and constexpr function - is this function a good candidate?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, constexpr

Code:

```
int CCalendarSettingsGooglePage::GetReminderIntervalAsMinutes(int iReminderUnitType, int iReminderInterval) noexcept
{
    int iMinutes = 24 * 60; // DEfault

    if (iReminderUnitType == ReminderUnitType::Weeks)
        iMinutes = iReminderInterval * 7 * 24 * 60;
    else if (iReminderUnitType == ReminderUnitType::Days)
        iMinutes = iReminderInterval * 24 * 60;
    else if (iReminderUnitType == ReminderUnitType::Hours)
        iMinutes = iReminderInterval * 60;
    else if (iReminderUnitType == ReminderUnitType::Minutes)
        iMinutes = iReminderInterval;

    return iMinutes;
}
```

Analysis warning:

> [C26497](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26497) You can attempt to make `CCalendarSettingsGooglePage::GetReminderIntervalAsMinutes` `constexpr` unless it contains any undefined behavior (f.4).

According to here (about [`constexpr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constexpr-cpp?view=msvc-160#:%7E:text=A%20constexpr%20function%20is%20one%20whose%20return%20value,values%2C%20a%20constexpr%20function%20produces%20a%20compile-time%20constant.) functions it does state:

> The following rules apply to `constexpr` functions in Visual Studio 2017 and later:
>
> - It may contain `if` and `switch` statements, and all looping statements including `for`, range-based `for`, `while`, and `do-while`.

But the original warning does say *unless it contains any undefined behavior*. How do we confirm if it has undefined behaviour? I do not think so, but did not want to blindly turn it into a `constexpr` function.

Comment: Signed integer overflow is [undefined in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16188263/1889329). Depending on the input the calculations can overflow. I believe the consequences of turning this function into a `constexpr` function are, that the compiler will reject the program with an error if the function is evaluated at compile time and the arguments cause the function to exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable Sounds like I should just suppress the warning then.