# Right angle triangle star pattern in C++ using while loops

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I want a pattern in which for n=4 in 1st row it has 4 stars and in 2nd row I has 1 space & 3 stars and in 3rd row, it has 2 spaces and 2 stars and so on.

```
****
 ***
  **
   *
```

The code, I tried to solve this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;

    int i = 1;
    while (i <= n)
    {
        //Printing Spaces

        int space = i - 1;
        while (space)
        {
            cout << " ";
            space++;
        }

        //Printing Stars

        int j = 1;
        while (j <= n)
        {
            cout << "*";
            j++;
        }
        cout << endl;
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int space = i - 1; while (space) { cout << " "; space++; }` If space starts out as a positive number and you add 1 to space inside the loop, when will `while (space)` ever be false? (especially since rolling over a signed integer is undefined behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

In your `while (space)` loop you aren't comparing `space` to anything, so it assumes that the expression is always true.

Here's a simplified way to do it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;

    int i = 1;
    while (i <= n)
    {
        // print i-1 spaces
        for (int j = i-1; j >= 1; j--)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        // print n-i+1 stars
        for (int j = n; j >= i; j--){
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I disagree with the first sentence. Writing `while (space)` is equivalent to writing `while ( space != 0 )`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;

    int i = 1;
    while (i <= n)
    {

        int space = i - 1;  
        while (space>=1)  // change 1.1
        {
            cout << " ";
            space--;      // change 1.2
        }

        int j = i;        // change2
        while (j <= n)
        {
            cout << "*";
            j++;
        }
        cout << endl;
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I made only 2 changes in your code so it can work.
**1st one**

> while (space>=1)

what you are doing is you are trying to add space in output so you add `space` variable in `while()` loop but that's not going to work because you have to decide first how many spaces you have to print according to that you have to put condition in `while()` loop. To achieve this `space--;` added .

For ex. line 4 `i=4;` space want 3, so `space=3; while(space>=1); space--;` so while loop runs 3 time and print 3 gaps/spaces.

**2nd one**

> int j = i;
>
> while (j <= n)

if you put `j=1;` then your gaps print properly but all stars print 4 times as loop runs 4 times always. Due to this condition for `i=1;` But if you make `j=i;`
loop runs 4 times for 1st line, 3 times for 2nd line,.....