# print condition while integer overflow not working

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getFectorial(int n)
{
    int ans = 1;
    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        ans = ans * i;
    }

    return ans;
}

int printNcr(int n, int r)
{
    if (getFectorial(n) > INT_MAX)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return (getFectorial(n)) / ((getFectorial(r)) * (getFectorial(n - r)));
}

int main()
{
    int n = 14;
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < row + 1; col++)
        {
            cout << printNcr(row, col) << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I give value of `n` more than 13th I want integer overflow condition should be working that given in `printNcr()` function, but it's not working and all line after 13th are printing wrong values instead of returning `false`.

How to make given `INT_MAX` condition work?

Comment: by definition an int can never be greater than INT_MAX

Comment: its not easy to detect signed overflow, once you overflow the product goes negative, but then it flips positive then negative. You can use unsigned instead but detecting overflow there is a mess too  - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-do-i-detect-unsigned-integer-overflow

Comment: It is spelled `factorial`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` oveflow cannot be reliably detected *after* it happens.

One way to detect upcoming `int` overflow in factorial:

```
int getFactorial(int n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    return 1; // and maybe other code when n < 0
  }
  int limit = INT_MAX/n;
  int ans = 1;
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    if (ans >= limit) {
      return INT_MAX; // Or some other code
    }
    ans = ans * i;
  }
  return ans;
}
```

Another way is at startup, perform a one-time calculation for maximum `n`.  With common 32-bit `int`, that limit is 12.

```
int getFactorial(int n) {
  if (n > getFactorial_pre_calculated_limit) {
    return INT_MAX;
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can detect overflow by watching for negative value

```
int getFectorial(int n)
{
    int ans = 1;
    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        ans = ans * i;
        if (ans < 0) <<<<======
            return -1;
    }

    return ans;
}
```

then

```
int printNcr(int n, int r)
{
    if (getFectorial(n) < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return (getFectorial(n)) / ((getFectorial(r)) * (getFectorial(n - r)));
}
```

Please note though that strictly speaking this is undefined behavior. It would be better to simply fail if you know the result is going to be too big (Ie n > 13)

Or better do it like this

```
int getFectorial(int n)
{
    long long ans = 1; <<<====
    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        ans = ans * i;
        if (ans >INT_MAX) <<<<======
            return -1;
    }

    return (int)ans;
}
```

or you could throw std::overflow_error

BTW the word is factorial not fectorial

Comment: I would probably just update `getFectorial()` to `throw` an exception on overflow, no need to check the result on exit.

Comment: I thought signed integer overflow [was undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16188263/10077).

Comment: @FredLarson - yup, updated answer

Comment: @pm100 Is `int` overflow _undefined behavior_ or is it specified to invoke `std::overflow_error`?

Comment: Off by 1 "going to be too big (Ie n > 13)" --> "(Ie n > 12)".

Comment: "if (ans < 0)" fails for 2 reasons: 1) `int` overflow is certainty UB 2) Typical result of `int` `ans * i` overflow is a truncated lower 32-bit response. In the case of 13! (which is 6227020800), the result is 1932053504.  Looking for `ans < 0`, at best, detects half of the multiplication overflows.